# Help in converting string to datetime in correct format

Tags: apex, datetime, format

I need to use a datetime in a SQL query and it expects it in format 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00'.

I have a string in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

How do I get the string formatted as the query wants it? I've tried parse and format but can't seem to get it right. Keep getting the error 'Invalid date/time: 4/10/2016 00:00:00 '.

Comment: are you trying this query using SOQL or SQL?

Comment: Could you provide a code or query example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String strdate = '12/27/2016';

Date newDate = Date.parse(strdate);

Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstanceGMT(newDate.year(), newDate.month(),newDate.day(),0,0,0);

Comment: Thank you so much! Been tearing my hair out with this :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value is d/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, should be 04/10/2016, also this could be because the format is MM/DD/YYYY where the system expects DD/MM/YYYY.

Assuming the field that holds your string dates is called "stringdates".

then you would do

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(20),stringdates,120)
```